# saving images from a url takes a long time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The below code successfully get the image from the link and stores into my cache directory. But I want to get many(like 100) images from different url(but on the same website, only the filename differs). This works fine for taking those images but i need to wait for a long time. is there anyway to get the images easily and make my responsive time really faster.

```
 NSString *UCIDLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/picture.png];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UCIDLink];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture.png"]];       

    NSError *writeError = nil;
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
    if (writeError) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
```

ghgh

Comment: The struggling point is most probably the bandwith. So anything improving your bandwith would speed up the process. This hasn't to do with your code.

Comment: How many downloads are you running concurrently?

Comment: @Bartdude Thanks I got a high speed connection and I am sure that same concept is implemented in Android and it works really quick.

Comment: @Wain Thanks, well it depends but approx I'm trying to download around 100 images in average. all the images are less than 500 KBs

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question about what you're doing currently. Try to download 5 at the same time and start new downloads as each download completes.

Comment: @Wain The problem I put this script in a loop so I need to get one image per iteration, and also I am fetching info from the database. It is not possible to download more than 1 at the same time. Any other option please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using take time to load image contents. so, prefer to load image asynchronously.

use below code:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(q, ^{
            /* Fetch the image from the server... */
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to
                 be what we just fetched. */
                cell.imgview.image = img;
            });
        });
```

or you can use:

```
AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,32,100, 100)];   
[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:your url]];
[YourImageView addSubview:asyncImageView];
[asyncImageView release];
```

**Download the Files from here.....
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView**

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-threading in order to make a number of image fetches happen simultaneously. That way, you can reduce your waiting time a lot.